# Scrapy Crawler multiple domains completes with no errors after retrieving source pages

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Trying to get Scrapy to crawl multiple domains.  i had it working briefly, but something changed and i have no idea what.  my understanding is that a "CrawlSpider" with rules about which links to follow should follow any allowed links until either the depth setting or the domain is exhausted.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class BbcSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bbcnews'
    allowed_domains = [
        'www.bbc.com']

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.bbc.com/news']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse', follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

and if i wanted to crawl multiple domains i would change the "allowed_domains" and "start_urls"

```
     allowed_domains = [
        'www.bbc.com',
        'www.voanews.com']

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.bbc.com/news',
        'https://www.voanews.com/p/6290.html']
```

However, in both cases when i run "scrapy crawl bbcnews", the crawler only retrieves the source sites then exits.

edit:

ok this code works as long as there is only 1 domain and 1 start URL.  if i add more than one of either, the spider only crawls the start pages.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class BbcfarsiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bbcfarsi'
    allowed_domains = ['bbc.com']
    start_urls = ['http://bbc.com/persian']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('persian'),), callback='parse', follow=True), )

def parse(self, response):
    pass
```

edit #2:
if i move the parse function outside the class, it works no problem.  The issue with that is that i cannot output anything that way.  having the parse function in the class (even if it is just filled with pass) results in only requesting the start pages and robot.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really sure why, but if i changed the rule callback to callback='parse_link' and renamed the function to match, everything worked just fine.  code should look something like what is below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class BbcSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bbcnews'
    allowed_domains = [
        'www.bbc.com',
        'www.voanews.com',]

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.bbc.com/news',
        'https://www.voanews.com/p/6290.html',]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_link', follow=True),)

    def parse_link(self, response):
        yield {
            'url' : response.url ,
        }
```

Edit: see Chetan mishra's comment below for the explanation. I clearly did not look at the documentation closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you are using **callback='parse'**, it is falling back to the inbuilt parse method.
Could you try using **callback='self.parse'** instead?
That might trigger your parse method and not the default one

Comment: gave it a try. same result.  it didn't actually perform what was in the defined parse function within the class and exited after the crawl of the "start_urls".

Comment: Seeing the code of CrawlSpider, this behavior seems to be expected.

They compile the rules in the init of CrawlSpider class and make a callable object of the method name you pass.
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py

If you pass 'parse', it will get redirected to the parse method inside the CrawlSpider class and not the one in your implementing class.
Even in the official documentation, they have used a method with a different name (parse_item)
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example